# Code only works in PHP8. How to make it work in PHP7?

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error "syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'".apparently this code only works for php 8.

```
 protected function google2faSecret(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn ($value) =>  decrypt($value),
            set: fn ($value) =>  encrypt($value),
        );
    }
```

Does anybody know how to make the code works in php 7?

Comment: Your problems are https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments So you have to remove `get:  set:` and maybe fill in the missing default parameter values.